# Wildfly 8.1.0 Final + Arquillian 1.1.5.Final = ArquillianServletRunner - No result returned

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

When I'm trying to run Arquillian tests on a remote Wildfly 8.1.0, I get the following stacktrace in the test results file:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Test set: com.tellyo.rtc.test.SimpleTest

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 61.214 sec <<< FAILURE!

testApplication(com.tellyo.rtc.test.SimpleTest)  Time elapsed: 1.38 sec  <<< ERROR!

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching test com.tellyo.rtc.test.SimpleTest public void com.tellyo.rtc.test.SimpleTest.testApplication()

at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:103)

at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:109)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)

at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:57)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)

at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)

at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:129)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)

at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:102)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)

at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:84)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)

at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)

at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)

at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:111)

at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$6.evaluate(Arquillian.java:294)

at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:269)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)

at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)

at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)

at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:193)

at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:345)

at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:49)

at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:207)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)

at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:155)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching request at http://0.0.0.0:7080/test/ArquillianServletRunner?outputMode=serializedObject&className=com.tellyo.rtc.test.SimpleTest&methodName=testApplication. No result returned

at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.executeWithRetry(ServletMethodExecutor.java:139)

at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:99)

... 78 more
```

I followed a handful of tutorials and forum topics but I couldn't find any solution to that problem and I believe I'm doing everything as I should be doing. My project consists of two ejb modules and one web module. I'm attaching the pom file of the main ejb module, the SImpleTest.java test class and also my arquillian.xml file. I'm not sure the structure of the project has anything to do with, though.

arquillian.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source Copyright 2013, Red Hat, Inc. 
    and/or its affiliates, and individual contributors by the @authors tag. See 
    the copyright.txt in the distribution for a full listing of individual contributors. 
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not 
    use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy 
    of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <!-- Uncomment to have test archives exported to the file system for inspection -->
    <!-- <engine> -->
    <!-- <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property> -->
    <!-- </engine> -->

    <!-- Force the use of the Servlet 3.0 protocol with all containers, as it 
        is the most mature -->
    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

    <!-- Example configuration for a remote JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 
        6 or AS 7 instance -->
    <container qualifier="wildfly" default="true">
        <!-- By default, arquillian will use the JBOSS_HOME environment variable. 
            Alternatively, the configuration below can be uncommented. -->
        <configuration>
            <property name="managementAddress">xxx</property>
            <property name="managementPort">0000</property>
            <property name="username">xxx</property>
            <property name="password">tellyxxxoadmin</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

</arquillian>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source Copyright 2013, Red Hat, Inc. 
    and/or its affiliates, and individual contributors by the @authors tag. See 
    the copyright.txt in the distribution for a full listing of individual contributors. 
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not 
    use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy 
    of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>tellyo-rtc</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.tellyo.rtc</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>tellyo-rtc-ejb</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>tellyo-rtc - ejb</name>

    <url>http://jboss.org/jbossas</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <properties>
        <jclouds.version>1.7.2</jclouds.version>
        <arq.version>1.1.5.Final</arq.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tellyo.rtc</groupId>
            <artifactId>tellyo-rtc-properties</artifactId>
            <type>ejb</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tellyo.stm</groupId>
            <artifactId>tellyo-stm-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All of them 
            are provided by JBoss AS 7 -->

        <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
        <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
        <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test scope dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
        <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and Transactional(JTA) 
            JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>${arq.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${arq.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-container-spi</artifactId>
            <version>${arq.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-core-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-test-spi</artifactId>
            <version>${arq.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-json-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
            <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0-rc</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jclouds dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>jclouds-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>jclouds-sshj</artifactId>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Rackspace UK dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.provider</groupId>
            <artifactId>rackspace-cloudservers-uk</artifactId>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.labs</groupId>
            <artifactId>rackspace-cloudfiles-uk</artifactId>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.provider</groupId>
            <artifactId>rackspace-cloudblockstorage-uk</artifactId>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.provider</groupId>
            <artifactId>rackspace-clouddatabases-uk</artifactId>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.labs</groupId>
            <artifactId>rackspace-cloudqueues-uk</artifactId>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.labs</groupId>
            <artifactId>rackspace-autoscale-us</artifactId>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.provider</groupId>
            <artifactId>rackspace-cloudloadbalancers-uk</artifactId>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.provider</groupId>
            <artifactId>rackspace-clouddns-uk</artifactId>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JDOM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.ejb.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Tell Maven we are using EJB 3.2 -->
                    <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it to run 
                just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
            <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including Arquillian 
                tests that execute in the specified container -->
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>


    </profiles>

</project>
```

SimpleTest.java

```
package com.tellyo.rtc.test;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SimpleTest {
    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createTestArchive() {

        JavaArchive ear = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "mytest.jar")
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        ear.addClasses(SimpleTest.class);

        System.out.println(ear.toString(true));
        return ear;
    }

    @Test
    public void testApplication() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(null);
    }
}
```

What I don't really understand is why the request in the exception above is launched at 0.0.0.0.

I can see in the server logs that the test application is indeed deployed:

```
2014-08-05 17:00:26,831 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS014900: Content added at location /opt/wildfly/standalone/data/content/f6/1fe7d564c3ef44a17443920a1b8a201787eb19/content

2014-08-05 17:00:26,848 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "test.war" (runtime-name: "test.war")

2014-08-05 17:00:27,236 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment test.war

2014-08-05 17:00:27,492 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: test.war

2014-08-05 17:00:27,585 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment test.war

2014-08-05 17:00:30,595 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /test

2014-08-05 17:00:30,812 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS018559: Deployed "test.war" (runtime-name : "test.war")

2014-08-05 17:01:14,637 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017535: Unregistered web context: /test

2014-08-05 17:01:14,674 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment test.war

2014-08-05 17:01:14,769 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test.war (runtime-name: test.war) in 139ms

2014-08-05 17:01:15,008 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS014901: Content removed from location /opt/wildfly/standalone/data/content/f6/1fe7d564c3ef44a17443920a1b8a201787eb19/content

2014-08-05 17:01:15,014 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS018558: Undeployed "test.war" (runtime-name: "test.war")
```

I don't know, though, why it's deployed as test.war, even though i specify a different name in the ShrinkWrap.create method in my SimpleTest class.

Another suspicious thing in the log file is this:

```
2014-08-05 16:38:08,561 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /0.0.0.0:7080
```

Why isn't Undertow assigned a proper IP address? Is this the way it's supposed to be?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to use Arquillian BOM to manage your dependencies. I have executed your Arquillian test using the below configuration and worked both for managed and remote WildFly.

You can find the code in this [arquillian-wildfly-example](https://github.com/tolis-e/arquillian-wildfly-example) GitHub repo for your convenience. Make sure to activate the [remote WidlFly profile](https://github.com/tolis-e/arquillian-wildfly-example/blob/master/pom.xml#L159) (managed is active by default) inside POM xml and also make the [wildfly-remote container configuration](https://github.com/tolis-e/arquillian-wildfly-example/blob/master/src/test/resources/arquillian.xml#L10) as default (default="true") in [arquillian.xml](https://github.com/tolis-e/arquillian-wildfly-example/blob/master/src/test/resources/arquillian.xml). In addition remove the `default="true"` from [wildfly-managed container configuration](https://github.com/tolis-e/arquillian-wildfly-example/blob/master/src/test/resources/arquillian.xml#L20) inside [arquillian.xml](https://github.com/tolis-e/arquillian-wildfly-example/blob/master/src/test/resources/arquillian.xml)

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.jboss.aerogear</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-wildfly-example</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.org.jboss.arquillian>1.1.5.Final</version.org.jboss.arquillian>
        <version.org.wildfly>8.1.0.Final</version.org.wildfly>
        <version.junit>4.11</version.junit>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-dependency-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [2.1,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <!-- Arquillian BOM (Bill Of Materials). -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

            <!-- JUnit regression testing framework. -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${version.junit}</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <profiles>

        <!-- Arquillian WildFly managed profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.org.wildfly}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <testResources>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    </testResource>
                </testResources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>unpack</id>
                                <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                            <version>${version.org.wildfly}</version>
                                            <type>zip</type>
                                            <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <!-- Arquillian WildFly remote profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>arq-widlfly-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.org.wildfly}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- JUnit regression testing framework. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit Container Implementation for the Arquillian Project -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**arquillian.xml**

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
            http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

        <!-- Sets the protocol which is how Arquillian talks and executes the tests inside the container -->
        <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

        <!-- Configuration to be used when the WidlFly remote profile is active -->
        <container qualifier="widlfly-remote">
            <configuration>
                <property name="managementAddress">X.X.X.X</property>
                <property name="managementPort">9990</property>
                <property name="username">admin</property>
                <property name="password">admin</property>
            </configuration>
        </container>

        <!-- Configuration to be used when the WildFly managed profile is active -->
        <container qualifier="widlfly-managed" default="true">
            <configuration>
                <property name="jbossHome">${jbossHome:target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final}</property>
            </configuration>
        </container>

    </arquillian>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. It turns out that the poms and xmls were fine. I was missing an interface binding in my standalone.xml file.

My public interface was set to

    <any-address/>

but when I changed it to 

    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management}"/>

it started working.

Comment: With your widlfly-remote configuration and the arquillian-wildfly-example, I got the same error (No result returned) :-( On the remote Linux server I ran a standalone Wildfly 8.1 server as it came out of the box, except for an added management user, and a management interface on <any-address/>. I am wondering what I am missing. Did you do any additional configuration of your remote Wildfly?

Comment: Exact error was: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching request at http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/ArquillianServletRunner?outputMode=serializedObject&className=org.arquillian.wildfly.example.BasicTest&methodName=shouldBeAbleTo. No result returned`

Comment: Problem could be solved by using managementAddress 127.0.0.1 and creating SSH tunnels from port 8080 and 9990 locally to remote host port 8080 and 9990. It works, but is not very elegant...